# Grabbing images from API

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, xcode8, uicollectionviewcell

I want to grab images from an api which gives the url of the image, do i need another api call to download the images from their url's? How do i grab every image and append it in an array and display them in my collection view cell. I have declared this outside the class scope 
`var videoArray = [funnyVideos]()`

```
Alamofire.request(_url).responseJSON { (response) in

    print(response.result.value!)
    if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        if let result = dict["result"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let data = result["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                for obj in data {
                    let mainObj = funnyVideos()
                    mainObj.parseData(from: obj)
                    videoArray.append(mainObj)
                    // print (obj)
                }

                if let image1 = data[0]["image"] as? String {        
                    print(image1)
                }

                self.collection.reloadData()   
            }   
        }
    }
    completed()
}
```

this function is another class: funny videos

```
func parseData(from: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
    if let name = from["title"] as? String{
        self._name = name.capitalized  
    }
}
```

this func configure cell is another class which holds the outlets for the label and imageview of collection cell.

```
func configureCell(_ funny : funnyVideos) {
    self.funny = funny
    nameLabel.text = self.funny.name.capitalized
    //   imageView.image = UIImage()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt      indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    fun = videoArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(fun)
}
```

what options do I have here to grab them from a url in the UIImage container? and `print(image1)` prints the url of the image.

Comment: Fix code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

You can use AlamofireImage for downloading image and set to the collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to call the url of images that fetch from json, to get image from url you can either use 
use like this

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
    guard let identifier = cellIdentifier else{
        fatalError("Cell identifier not provided")
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier ,
                                                                     for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
```

let imageUrl = arrayImage[indexPath.row]

cell.imageView.setImage(url:"imageUrl")

return cell

}

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to make another api call on image's url. You can use AlamofireImage or sdwebimage library for download images.

First hit Api with normal Alamofire library and get link of all images and save them in dict or array . Then make another api call using AlamofireImage or sdwebimage.

you should try sdwebimage becauz it is easy

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Swift library called [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
It will handle caching as well as downloading of the images when you provide the URLs.
Here is the link for getting started. [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet)